# Initialize the property at class level will allocate memory during load or constructor?

Tags: java, memory, jvm

We have class let's say AnimalShelter which has a list of animals. When we will initialize it at the class level, it will create memory during a load of class or during the creation of the object.

```
class Animal{
  String name;
}

class AnimalShelter{
  private List<Animal> animals = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

My understanding is that it will initialize the property during memory load or when we construct an object it will create an object with a new list. One initialization is always at the class level.

If we initialize the list in the constructor, it will have just a reference, and when we create an object will assign memory. There is no memory allocate at the class level

```
class AnimalShelter{
  private List<Animal> animals; 
  AnimalShelter(){
    animals  = new ArrayList<>();
  }
}
```

How we can verify this thing or I am totally wrong about this understanding?

Comment: You are totally wrong.  These do the same thing; they create the ArrayList when the AnimalShelter is constructed.

Comment: @LouisWasserman so until the property is not static there is no memory allocation. is it right?

Comment: Neither version allocates until an AnimalShelter is constructed, because the field isn't static.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Okay got your point. Then why we prefer to initialize inside the constructor. is there a specific reason or its just a personal choice?

Comment: @VimitDhawan Yes, this initializes in all constructors implicitly.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut okay got it. so it will create everything during instance creation only. Yeah, I think it makes sense also if we can't access it at the class level why we need to create. Thanks

Comment: Just keep in mind: static ➝ class level. Non static ➝ instance level.

Comment: These two variants produce exactly the same bytecode. I don’t know who “we” is, but definitely not “every developer”. There is no reason to prefer the second variant.

Comment: @Holger Thanks for sharing the byte code information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [JLS 16](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/), section 12.5 *Creation of New Class Instances*, when an instance is created, then in order:

1. Assign the arguments for the constructor to newly created parameter variables
   for this constructor invocation.
2. If this constructor begins with an explicit constructor invocation  of
   another constructor in the same class (using this), then evaluate the arguments
   and process that constructor invocation recursively using these same five
   steps. If that constructor invocation completes abruptly, then this procedure
   completes abruptly for the same reason; otherwise, continue with step 5.
3. This constructor does not begin with an explicit constructor invocation of
   another constructor in the same class (using this). If this constructor is for
   a class other than Object, then this constructor will begin with an explicit
   or implicit invocation of a superclass constructor (using super). Evaluate the
   arguments and process that superclass constructor invocation recursively using
   these same five steps. If that constructor invocation completes abruptly, then
   this procedure completes abruptly for the same reason. Otherwise, continue
   with step 4.
4. Execute the instance initializers and instance variable initializers for this class,
   assigning the values of instance variable initializers to the corresponding
   instance variables, in the left-to-right order in which they appear textually in
   the source code for the class. If execution of any of these initializers results
   in an exception, then no further initializers are processed and this procedure
   completes abruptly with that same exception. Otherwise, continue with step 5.
5. Execute the rest of the body of this constructor. If that execution completes
   abruptly, then this procedure completes abruptly for the same reason.
   Otherwise, this procedure completes normally.

For instance, the following will print A, B, C, D, E in this order. Note that while the C block comes *after* the constructor in the source code, it is executed *before*, because instance initializers are all executed *before* the constructor.

```
public class Test {
    {
        System.out.println("A");
    }
    
    Sub sub = new Sub();
    
    public Test() {
        System.out.println("D");
    }
        
    {
        System.out.println("C");
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        var test = new Test();
        System.out.println("E");
    }
}

class Sub {
    public Sub() {
        System.out.println("B");
    }
}
```